# Obtener el value Jquery de button con mismo id='remover'

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Buen día amigos tengo un problema, tengo un foreach donde imprimi un botton con id="remover" con diferentes value, quisiera que al precionar el boton me mandara el value de ese boton para despues procesarlo con una peticion ajax y enviar ese dato por post.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<br>
<button id="remover" value="PC150">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button id="remover" value="GSX20">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button id="remover" value="TC300">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button id="remover" value="QW300">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
  
</div>
```

Más o menos así son mis botones pero con diferente value. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener el value el botón que estoy presionando aunque todos tengan el mismo ID='remover'?, para despues enviar ese valor por post a otra página.

Comment: Utiliza clases, los Id deben ser únicos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay un concepto que estas olvidando ,los identificadores (ID) deben ser **únicos** siempre .

Tal y como está su código `HTML` es incorrecto , en lugar de `ID`  podría usar clases y así añadir el `listener` adecuado para el evento `click`.

```js
//Seleccionamos los elementos con la clase remover
var botones = document.querySelectorAll('.remover');
//Iteramos los elemetos obtenidos
botones.forEach(el =>{
  // Añadimos el Listener par el evento click
  el.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    //Imprimimos en consola en value del botón clickeado
    // el botón estará referenciado por e.target
    console.log(e.target.value);
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="remover" value="PC150">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button class="remover" value="GSX20">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button class="remover" value="TC300">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button class="remover" value="QW300">ELIMINAR</button>
```

Con Jquery Sería más sencillo

```js
$('.remover').click(function(e) {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="remover" value="PC150">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button class="remover" value="GSX20">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button class="remover" value="TC300">ELIMINAR</button> 
<br>
<button class="remover" value="QW300">ELIMINAR</button>
```

Comment: Wow justo lo que estaba buscando muchas gracias, ahora mismo lo voy a implementar.

Comment: @ManueelPerezz qué bueno,  Igual recibí un downvote sin alguna justificación para mejorar quizá :) pero bueno ya está . Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que hay que cambiar las cosas un poco, primero por el estándar HTML no puedes tener ids iguales, así que cuando los imprimas tendrás que concatenar en el ID algún identificado, sea un entero secuencial o hasta el mismo value.

Luego de esto lo que necesitas hacer en javascript es hacer bind de esos botones al evento de onclick para enviar el el dato vía ajax.

Comment: Al obtener el  valor lo puedo guardar en una variable y enviarlo por ajax,no? porque ese es el que se va a remover.

Comment: cuando le haces bind a una función en un node del dom, en este caso un botón, el scope de la función es el elemento, deberías dentro de dicha función hacer un this.value y ya la tienes.

Comment: @sergiosusa intenta en tu proxima respuesta agregar un ejemplo de la solucion. Asi te ira mucho mejor ;)